# Android Webview Tutorial

Tags: android, webview, sdk

I'm following this guide:
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted

To make a simple app to show a view of my website using webview, fact is i downloaded android studio and the guide is not up to date with it (missing the file fragment_main.xml), so i'm absolutely clueless about what i have to do to have my webview up and running, any help?

The onCreate method modified, it cannot resolve symbol webView, webSettings and method setJavaScriptEnabled

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.example.example;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView mWebView;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://beta.html5test.com/");
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

and my activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please post all the code of your activity and also the error log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2**

You have to import the relative class "WebSettings"
add this line to the imports: `import android.webkit.WebSettings;`

This is the MainActivity.java that WORK for me

```
package com.example.example.example;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://beta.html5test.com/");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Remember to add the "internet permission" to the Manifest like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

**Update 1**

You have declared the variable with the name "mWebView" but in the method you use "webView" so solve it.

I think this code should work:

```
private WebView mWebView;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://beta.html5test.com/");
}
```

**Before:**

Did you declare the variable ?

Like `private WebView webView;` before the onCreate method

and also you are mismatching the variable "webView" with the class "WebView" that have capitol letter.

change this line  `WebSettings webSettings = WebView.getSettings();`

with this line: `WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();`

Comment: yep i forgot to add that

Comment: check also the variable name. You are using the class and not the object with webSettings

Comment: Ok. Please post the entire code and the complete error log. Did you change the line with "webView.getSettings();" that  I told you ?

Comment: Can you put please all the code and the line where is the error ? it's hard like this beacuse I don't know if there is other code.

Comment: Well, you didn't import the WebSetting from webkit. Check my answer I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

**Webview class**

```
WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_advertising);
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Webview layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Manifest permission**

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`